# randomly failing acceptance-tests with Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object

Tags: testing, ember.js

Some of my acceptance-tests (which involve actions) fail randomly when run with all other tests but never fail when I run them in isolation.

The `Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object` is triggered in my action

I don't get any issue while using the table as a user so these issues only appear in tests. So I'm not sure if it's just because the app isn't destroyed correctly after each run.

Can I somehow see why the object is about to be destroyed or which observers are blocking it?

**foos/index/route.js**

```
startFoo(foos) {
  foos.forEach(function(foo) {
    foo.set('status', 'active');
    foo.save();
  });
},
```

This `action` gets passed down to a component (table) which shows a list of `foo`-models. Each row can be selected, doing so add the `foo` model of this row to a property `selectedRows` on this table component.

**components/my-table/table.js**

```
visibleColumns: Ember.A(),
selectedRows: Ember.A(),

selectRow(row) {
  let selectedRows = this.get('selectedRows');
  if (selectedRows.contains(row)) {
    selectedRows.removeObject(row);
  } else {
    selectedRows.addObject(row);
  }
},
isSelected(row) {
  return this.get('selectedRows').contains(row);
},
```

**components/my-table/header/template.hbs**

`action.cb` is the function `startFoo`

```
<button {{action action.cb table.selectedRows}}>
  {{im-icon icon=action.icon}}
</button>
```

The table component is pretty modular so it has `header`, `columns`, `cells`, `rows` and to share the state (like selected rows) I use an `Ember.Object` which is passed to all parts of the table component (which might be the issue?!!?)

**components/my-table/row/component.js**

```
isSelected: computed('table.selectedRows.[]', {
  get(/*key*/) {
    return this.get('table').isSelected(this.get('content'));
  },
  set(/*key, value*/) {
    this.get('table').selectRow(this.get('content'));
    return this.get('table').isSelected(this.get('content'));
  },
}),
```

**components/my-table/row/template.hbs**

`content` is a `foo` model

```
<td class="shrink">{{input type='checkbox' checked=isSelected}}</td>
{{#each table.visibleColumns as |column|}}
  {{my-table/cell content=content column=column}}
{{/each}}
```

**Test**

setup and teardown is `ember-cli` [default](https://github.com/seanpdoyle/ember-cli/blob/4d94b311a094941d141d5730609c895eb3be385a/blueprints/app/files/tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance.js)

```
moduleForAcceptance('Acceptance | Foos');

test('click on action start changes state to active', function(assert) {
  server.create('foo', {
    status: 'paused'
  });

  // This is an ember-page-object
  fooPage
    .visit()
    .selectFoo()
    .clickStart();

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(fooPage.foos(1).status(), 'active', 'runs action');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking `isDestroyed` prior to setting should do the trick

```
isSelected: computed('table.selectedRows.[]', {
  get(/*key*/) {
    return this.get('table').isSelected(this.get('content'));
  },
  set(/*key, value*/) {
    if (this.get('isDestroyed')) {
      return;
    }
    this.get('table').selectRow(this.get('content'));
    return this.get('table').isSelected(this.get('content'));
  },
}),
```

Comment: It will solve the issue obviously, but it seems like more a hack. And I don't really want to use special code just because tests are failing and my app works.

I have this check in older apps already and still have the feeling something is not built 'the ember' way